# Recovery Partition DOES NOT EXIST of my windows 8 netbook

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, netbook

When my netbook Samsung Series 5 np535u3c was brought to a shop for a repair my HDD Memory was changed together with my Battery, although it was changed with brand new and original parts my netbook just says 'coz some of my function keys doesn't work anymore and when I tried to reset it's setting to default it says **"Some files are missing. Your Windows installation or recovery media will provide these files"**

I downloaded Recovery Software, SW Update to my pc. When Recovery Software was downloaded it was on installation process that a message suddenly pop on my screen from SW Update that **"Recovery Partition does not exist.. installation cancelled"**

Comment: We can't.  The shop that repaired your laptop didn't place the recovery sector on the hdd.

Comment: If it does not exist then there is nothing we can do. Your manufacturer may be able to provide you a DVD with recovery software or your computer but they may charge you for it. The shop you took the computer to seemingly failed to copy over your recovery partition. Do you still have the old HDD? If so, is it still usable? You may be able to copy the partition over but it would be a lot of work, otherwise you may be able to use it to create a recovery USB stick.

Comment: In short there is nothing anyone here can do to help you without physically having your PC and old hard drive or your manufacturer recovery discs.

Comment: oh, that's why sir. When I took my computer to that shop, it surprised me when the technician told me, changing my pc's battery affect my HDD memory (my computer is presently under warranty). When I asked the technician about the HDD Memory the technician told me that the HDD Memory was sent to Manufacturers so as a answer to your question if I still have my old HDD, I fell down 'coz I don't have it.

Comment: If I have my old HDD memory so there'll be chances of fixing it right? But i took my computer to that shop couple of months ago.

Comment: If you had the HDD then the answer would be "maybe", it is difficult to say if you will be able to get recovery data from it or if it would be usable.  Your best bet is to contact your manufacturer and ask them if you can get a set of recovery media for your computer, they may charge you for the media though.

Comment: hope the shop where I bought this netbook could help. Will the charges for the media costs very expensive sir? Hope not. Lol :D
thanks sir.